# SQL innerjoin 4 tables

Tags: sql

I'm trying to make a page where i can see who answered what question whit what.
I've the following tables :

```
-(poeple_who_ask)
(id)
(username)

-(questions)
(id)
(id_who_ask)
(question) 

-(choises)
(id)
(id_question) 
(choise)

-(persons_who_answer)
(id)
(id_who_ask)
(id_question)
(username)  

-(answers)
(id)
(id_question)
(id_choise)
(id_person)
```

Now i'm trying to make some innerjoin query's to fill a couple of pages.

-query to get what poeple answerd on a question.
 -who did not answerd.

every innerjoin query i make ends up in a error :(
could someone help me whit this?
I'm rather new at innerjoin :)
maybe mine tables are wrong :) all positife answers could help me one the way:)

questions are multiple answerd like : what colors are the flag -> red white blue / green yelllow blue / purple green yellow

thnx in advanced

edit: eventulie i want it implemented in a site where the person who asks can see who did answered what and who not....

Comment: please show your attempts at innerjoin queries and how they failed.

Comment: Edit your question and show sample data and desired results.

Comment: edited :) thnx for the tip gordon.
@jochem sorry i did to many trys and searches on google before comming tho here :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
SELECT
  q.id         AS QuestionID,
  q.question   AS Questoin,
  ask.username AS PersonWhoAsked,
  pa.username  AS PersonWhoAnswered,
  c.choise     AS AnswerChoice
FROM questions AS q
INNER JOIN people_who_ask     AS ask ON q.id_who_ask   = ask.id
INNER JOIN answers            AS a   ON q.id           = a.id_question
INNER JOIN choises            AS c   ON a.id_choice    = c.id
INNER JOIN persons_who_answer AS pa  ON a.id_person    = pa.id 
                                    AND pa.id_question = q.id;
```

**Note that,** if a question doesn't have an answer, it won't be present in this table, to include those questions that don't have answers, you have to use `LEFT JOIN` like this:

```
SELECT
  q.id         AS QuestionID,
  q.question   AS Questoin,
  ask.username AS PersonWhoAsked,
  t.username  AS PersonWhoAnswered,
  t.choise     AS AnswerChoice
FROM questions AS q
INNER JOIN people_who_ask     AS ask ON q.id_who_ask   = ask.id
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT a.id_question, c.choice, pa.username
  FROM answers AS a
  INNER JOIN choises            AS c   ON a.id_choice    = c.id
  INNER JOIN persons_who_answer AS pa  ON a.id_person    = pa.id 
) AS t ON t.id_question = q.id;
```

Comment: thnx for your answer, i'll try this tonight to implement :)

Comment: thnx for the answer and i tried it now... very helpfull and learned something.... but sorry not what i wanted , i editet mine question :) thnx

Comment: the second query whit the left join-> where does the letter t come from in t.choise and t.username???

Comment: @hexedecimal - it comes from the alias of the subquery after the left join I put it as an alias you can rename it to whatever you want.

Comment: thnx mahmoud (Y) but euhmmm (sorry i'm new at this.... where can i 'set' a question to show... like ( WHERE question.id = "1") -->eventulie i want it implemented in a site where the person who asks can see who did answered what and who not....